# relays 5V 10A and 12V 30V stop working after a few days of use

Tags: relay, heat, dimmer, snubber

[image]

We built a system for heating 3 bioelectrochemical reactors, but after a certain time of operation the system starts to heat up. We identified that when this occurs, the relay works despite the light being on (indicating that it is activated) while the voltage is at 0 V on the heating strips (added 3.3 A).

the load of system is AC. The relay I was using was 4 ways 5V 10 A (10A/250VAC and 10A/30VDC)

When we change the relay, the problem is resolved for a while, until the relay is heated up and functioning again - (in this case, the malfunction of the relay starts only with one of the relays and later as other routes stopped working - after a few days.

Considering that the problem was the relay, we decided to replace it with a more robust one, we changed it to 12 V 30A, it worked for 20 days and then 1 of the 3 relays stopped working - (but still with the light on) then the heating stopped. With this I exchange the relay for one of the same type and it is working for the time being

We use the dimmer to control the voltage and avoid an overheating problem if it occurs, however in such a way that the 3 reactors keep heating (do you think this would cause some problem in the relay)?

What do you think might be causing this relay problem? and how could you prevent the heating/operation from being interrupted?

thanks
JC

Comment: I'm not going to try to make heads or tails of the diagram you have, but are the loads AC or DC?  Is the relay rated for DC?

Comment: Several suggestions: You cannot use a dimmer on the input of a regulated power supply like that.  Search for "relay coil driver" and see how to limit the current on a relay coil (high current to actuate, lower current to hold).  Stop using cheap Chinese relay boards, their quality varies widely.

Comment: the snubbers are supposed to go across the relays, not the loads. I'm surprised the relays heat up - even for cheapy 10A ones so there must be something fundamentally wrong, like 12 volts into 5V relays??  Nevertheless, the wiring is an electrical nightmare. Please get someone competent to assist you before you burn the lab down or electrocute yourself.

Comment: I agree with Dean Franks and Kartman. Speaking in my experience try a better power supply. You can use for example a Thermaltake ATX 600w and will be no issues. Regarding to connections get someone it can help you, electricity with those voltages and currents are not toys. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Julio, A good schematic would fetch the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanical relays have a life in the 50,000 to 100,000 operations range at full current. You can look up the particular datasheets for those in your relay boards.

If the relays are carrying close to full current and are switching every few seconds 24/7 they will not last long. For example, 100,000 operations at 3 seconds per cycle will wear the relay out in about 3 days.

You can use the relays to switch more robust contactors, slow down the switching rate (for example, a couple times a minute rather than every few seconds), or use solid-state relays. Each have their pluses and negatives. Solid state relays produce quite a bit of heat (roughly 1W per ampere) and tend to fail 'on' in case of voltage or current surges. Mechanical contactors are robust but noisy (electrically and acoustically) and are inductive, requiring some care driving them (eg. snubbers or small suitable solid-state relays). Slowing down the cycle time can cause excessive swings in temperature.